# How get Mathematica to recognize a simple trigonometric identity

Tags: differential-geometry

I am experimenting with simple differential geometry problem, computing the Frenet apparatus.

```
beta = {-(4/5) Sin[s], -Cos[s], (3/5) Sin[s]}
{-((4 Sin[s])/5), -Cos[s], (3 Sin[s])/5}
myT = D[beta, s]
{-((4 Cos[s])/5), Sin[s], (3 Cos[s])/5}
kappa = Norm[D[myT, s]]
Sqrt[Abs[Cos[s]]^2 + Abs[Sin[s]]^2]
```

Obviously, kappa=1. How can I get Mathematica to recognize this fact?

Comment: `Simplify[kappa, Element[s, Reals]]`?

Comment: You could also say `Resolve[ForAll[s, kappa == 1], Reals]`

Comment: Maybe your wording needs clarification, because it's not entirely clear what you mean by "Mathematica recognizing this fact." If you want a simplified form of `kappa`, use @kglr's `Simplify`, if you want to test if this assumption holds, use `Resolve` with `ForAll` as I commented above.